# Excract JPanel into new class in NetBeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, refactoring

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691890/reusing-a-jpanel-in-netbeans-gui-designer) question, except the code is already written.

I have

```
JFrame
  JTabbedPane
    JPanel X
      <...>
    JPanel Y
      <...>
    JPanel Z
      <...>
```

all defined in the same class, but I want to move each panel into its own .java file. I really don't want to manually copy-paste from the underlying .form and .java files if I don't have to. Each panel is mostly decoupled from the others already, which is why I want to create separate files for each.

What is the best way to split this into four separate classes (1 JFrame, 3 JPanels) using NetBeans so that it will move all of its autogenerated code correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new JPanelX class in Netbeans. Then copy-paste the contents of JPanel X into JPanelX. Repeat for each of the others.

Then in JFrame, remove the JPanel's and replace them with your new JPanelX, etc.