# Convert JAR to Swing Component

Tags: java, swing, jar

I have created a JAR file, which contains JPanel that has Calendar function.
It acts completely like JCalendar, but I have no idea how to make it a Swing Component/Control.

I know I can just use JCalendar, but I wanna make my own. The problem is just that I can't make it treated as Swing Control.

Any helps/suggestions/tuts link would be appreciated :)

**Edited:**
Example: We have imported JCalendar to our project library, next is to import it to palette using tools-palette-swing/awt components, add from jar, select the JCalendar, select which class from JCalendar you want to use, select the categories (swing control etc), and the selected class will show up in the categories we chose. But mine doesn't showing up at all, netbeans doesn't recognize my class as swing component. But in palette tool my class exists in the selected category but marked as unknown.

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of WindowBuilder? E.g. in Eclipse?

Comment: Could you specify the IDE you're using ? BTW you have to make it a `JavaBean` so that you can use it in a visual swing editor

Comment: There's only 1 class, and it extends JPanel, I make this class using NetBeans Drag n Drop feature

Comment: Also, if your issue is using your component in the NetBeans code builder (you still don't tell us!), look at [this link](http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/how-create-and-import-a-javabe). It's somewhat dated but will have useful info.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: updated, hope it will clear the question :)

Comment: @A-SM: thank you for the update. Down-vote removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Class you make that extends a Swing Component, is a Swing Component.

Your class should have the `extend` keyword and actually extend such a class instead of being a wrapper.

### Update

To add custom components to netbeans:

- [Reusing a JPanel in NetBeans GUI Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691890/reusing-a-jpanel-in-netbeans-gui-designer)
- [How to include custom panel with NetBeans GUI Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816286/how-to-include-custom-panel-with-netbeans-gui-builder)
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormUsingCustomComponent

Comment: But it already extends JPanel, as I make it using NetBeans Drag n Drop.

Comment: Aha..so your issue is that you can't have your component visible in netbeans. Answer is updated.